# Prevent PHP writing array data to /tmp folder

Tags: mysql

Running a LAMP stack on newly-deployed CentOS 7 server. PHP 7.

I have an internal resource-intensive script that builds large PHP arrays to store data prior to parsing/writing it. It all worked fine until we migrated to the new server.

After a few minutes, the script terminates with the following error:

```
Error writing file '/tmp/MYxJXajd' (Errcode: 28 "No space left on device")
```

I checked and my `/tmp` partition is quite small. However I want to avoid resizing the partition just for the benefit of this one script, so I thought I would simply change the directory where this specific data is being written to a directory on the main (bigger) partition.

I used `session_save_path()` to change the session directory location, and can confirm this takes fine.

However, the same error still persists, so there must be some other process/setting that is writing data to the `/tmp` directory for the purposes of storing array data. However when doing a text search on `phpinfo()` output, `/tmp` does not appear anywhere, so am not sure what else I can change.

Any ideas?

Comment: It may be useful to see the script thats failing and a complete error message. Or we could just play 20 guesses

Comment: Yes I should have searched the specific error before asking a question. It's evidently a MySQL issue, have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly answering this. This specific error (28) is caused by MySQL running out of space writing temporary files, not PHP. Just need to change the `tmpdir` variable on mysql configuration and grant it permissions to the appropriate user.